# NodeJS ftp to upload data instead of file?

Tags: node.js, ftp, upload

Is it possible to upload a buffer/data to FTP as opposed to reading a file/path to an FTP server in NodeJS?

So far, most of the examples are using files.
ftp.put('filename', '/remote/path').

I want to do something like:
let data  = '123,3232,121sdaa';
ftp.put(data, '/remote/file.txt');

Answer (score 0):

Try this to upload buffer data,

```
npm install jsftp
```

Comment: I tried it, but it gives me a file not found error -- I dont want to upload file, but write data to a remote file.

Comment: let data = '123,3232,121sdaa'; 

ftp.put(data, 'file.txt');

Do I need to create a buffer for data? The remote path is correct.

Comment: try absolute path with __dirname.

Comment: For the remote or local? I do not want to create a new file on local...only push a buffer data to the remote path. You mean like ftp.put(data, __dirname + '/file.txt'); ?

Comment: don't create new file, you just read file data and store it somewhere else like db or any other ftp server.

do you have multiple system? 
if yes then open ftp of other system and save data to it by using ip.